# Mean preserving spread for normal distribution

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, means

Is it true that any two normal distributions with the same mean can be ordered w.r.t. the relation of a mean preserving spread? My intuition would be that this is true but I cannot come up with a formal proof.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by a "mean preserving spread"? An example, perhaps?

Comment: A distribution F_B is a mean preserving spread of a distribution F_A if both distributions have the same mean and i if the area under F A  from minus infinity to x is less than or equal to that under F_B  from minus infinity to x for all real numbers x with strict inequality at some x. Intuitively, both distributions have the same mean but one distribution puts more probability weight on "the middle".

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought it was a _sui generis_ term. I should have researched before asking.

Comment: That's alright :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: If both normal distributions have the same mean $\mu$, there is a positive constant $c$ such that $F_1(x + \mu) = F_2(c x + \mu)$ where $F_1$ and $F_2$ are the CDF's.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Using the first definition from Wiki,

> Let $x_{A}$ and $x_{B}$ be the random variables associated with gambles A and B. Then B is a mean-preserving spread of A if and only if $x_{B} \overset{d}{=}(x_{A}+z)$ for some random variable $z$ having $E(z\mid x_{A})=0$ for all values of $x_{A}$. Here $\overset{d}{=}$ means "is equal in distribution to" (that is, "has the same distribution as").

For $\sigma^2_2>\sigma^2_1$ we can heuristically write $N(\mu,\sigma^2_1) \overset{d}{=} N(\mu,\sigma^2_2) +N(\mu,\sigma^2_2 - \sigma^2_1)$.

The proof of the equivalence of the definition can be found in [Rothschild and Stiglitz 1970](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022053170900384?via%3Dihub) or [Machina and Pratt 1997](https://www.jstor.org/stable/41760845)